# Unity, Android can't search the sqlite data base

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a folder /Assets/StreamingAssets to save the db there, then I use this to load db:

```
dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection ("URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/assets/Timmy_Game.db");
dbconn.Open();
```

But when I'm in my phone the game can't find the db.

I tried this too:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Timmy_Game.db";

            if (!File.Exists (path)) {
                WWW loadDB = new WWW ("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "/assets/Timmy_Game.db");

                while (!loadDB.isDone) {}
                File.WriteAllBytes (path, loadDB.bytes);
            }

            dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection ("URI=file:" + path);
```

But didn't work.

Comment: I cannot speak for Unity, but in standard Android, assets are not files on the filesystem.

Comment: I had edited the post look what I did too...

Comment: Do you have access to the db file and can you search it via SQLite commandline tool? That would verify the database integrity and the correctness of your search query, without the Android stuff as a man in the middle. Can you give more details on how exactly it did not work, how is the failure to find the db indicated? Does it sound more like a file not found or more like a file content not understood?

Comment: It seems like he can do copy the file (what is done in the if), but when I try the dbconn.Open(); it crush.

I tryed to put an exception and it returns sqlite3... (If I make an SQLiteException it don't work)